# Dynamic List - how to replicate column A removing duplicates in column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A & B are source columns, C is desired result.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 7 | 7 |
| 8 | 7 | 9 |
| 9 | 8 | 10 |
| 10 | 9 | 11 |
| 11 | 10 | 12 |
| 12 | 11 | 13 |
| 13 | 12 | 14 |
| 14 | 13 | 15 |
| 15 | 14 | 16 |
| 16 | 15 | 17 |
| 17 | 16 | 18 |
| 18 | 17 | 19 |
| 19 | 18 | 20 |
| 20 | 19 | 21 |
| 21 | 20 | 22 |
| 22 | 21 | 23 |
| 23 | 22 | 24 |
| 24 | 23 | 26 |
| 25 | 23 |  |
| 26 | 24 |  |

I'm using =FILTER($A1:$A27,$B2:$B28<>$B1:$B27) - which does remove the duplicates, but keeps the second instance. (Also copies the header row, which is useful.)

I suspect there's going to be a better way of doing this altogether though. Thanks for any help.

Comment: So you are saying there could be more than two duplicates in column B:B and you wish to keep the very last one (from its neighboring A:A cell)? If so, try: `=FILTER(A1:A26,ROW(A1:A26)=XMATCH(B1:B26,B1:B26,0,-1))` which should still keep the header.

Comment: @JvdV good solution, but why XMATCH for reverse search instead MATCH? `=FILTER(A1:A26,ROW(A1:A26)=MATCH(B1:B26,B1:B26,0))` generate the desiderate list

Comment: @Terio, from what I understood op was looking to leave the latest of each dupe in the filtered list. Could be wrong ofcourse

Comment: @JvdV seeing the example *C* column I understood he wanted the first value: eg. 6, 7, **9**, 10 and not 6, 8, 9, 10

Comment: @Terio, then just match would do yes

Comment: @TrevorA can you explain your question? We have a doubt ...

Comment: Sorry for not being ckear, yes the request was to keep the first instance. My original formula kept the 2nd instance. The xmatch reverse search does the job. Thanks all.

Comment: @JvdV Sir please post as an `Answer` for benefit of the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To close the question; as per comments, use `MATCH()`:

```
=FILTER(A1:A26,ROW(A1:A26)=MATCH(B1:B26,B1:B26,0))
```